# Why do my email drafts linger in my Outlook drafts folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, office365

Whenever I type an email or a reply to an email, the email draft remains in my drafts folder, even after sending them. This is really confusing for me, since it makes me think that I haven't sent them yet, even though I did. However, unlike the problem in [Outlook Emails are Sent but stored in drafts (Not what you think)](https://superuser.com/questions/578010/outlook-emails-are-sent-but-stored-in-drafts-not-what-you-think), I *can* delete these drafts without errors.

I have tried the solution from [Outlook 2013 + Gmail leads to many messages in drafts even after it is sent](https://superuser.com/questions/558044/outlook-2013-gmail-leads-to-many-messages-in-drafts-even-after-it-is-sent), but I get an error that I can't unsubscribe from that folder because it's a special Outlook folder.

I'm using Outlook 15 from the Office 365 package, with an IMAP account configured. About 2 months ago, right after the release of Windows 10, I completely reinstalled Windows, and I installed Office 365 a few weeks ago. This is not an Exchange account. However, I do have access to a webmail interface.

Is there a way for me to fix this so that drafts no longer remain in my Drafts folder after sending them?

Comment: It's probably because Windows sends and receives emails at regular intervals, but you probably already checked that. On the online version, in checks for new messages regularly, but when you send a message, it instantly sends it - no draft linger needed. You are using the desktop software, right? I'd say check and see how long the timeout is on the `Send and Receive` option, and also check to see if you've got a strong connection to your imap server. I know the network I use carries a heavy load and tends to lag at times.

Comment: Where can I find that send&receive timeout option? My IMAP server is for the mail of my ISP, and I haven't really got connection issues with it. I also am not sure if it's even a timeout issue, because I even had a time when I noticed the draft remaining a day after I sent the mail.

Comment: Hmm... that sounds troublesome. :/ Have you looked in File > Options and looked at the send/receive time? That's the only suggestion I can think of. What's it say in the bottom-right corner? It should say `Connected to: {Servername}`. If not, it's the connection, though you say it's a strong connection, sometimes the software refuses to send it... I'll keep searching and see if I can find something a bit more helpful.

Comment: I can't find that send/receive time anywhere in the File > Options menu. I assume it's a textbox or a dropdown and not just a simple checkbox? That's also the File > Options menu of Outlook itself, right? In the bottom-right corner, it says "VERBONDEN", which is Dutch for "CONNECTED". It doesn't mention a server name.

Comment: Sorry, but that's all I could find. At this point, I'd go to office.com, get a fresh install of the software, and reinstall the entire thing - but if I were able to see the program, I'd probably have found a solution, but that's if Microsoft intends for one to exist. If I find out anything else, I'll let you know, but at this point, I'm at a loss for words.